# How to add list items to a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a function named `addToInventory(inventory, addedItems)`, where the
inventory parameter is a dictionary representing the player’s inventory "stuff" and the addedItems parameter is a list like dragonLoot.

The function should add the items in the list to the players inventory.

```
stuff = {'rope':1, 'torch':6, 'gold coins':42, 'dagger':1, 'arrow':12}

dragonLoot = ['gold coins', 'dagger', 'gold coins', 'gold coins', 'ruby']

def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for n in range(0, len(addedItems)):
        new_inv = inventory.copy()
        for k, v in (new_inv.items()):
            if k == addedItems[n]:
                v += 1
            else:
                new_inv[str(addedItems[n])] = 1

def displayInventory(inventory):
    print("Inventory:")
    item_total = 0
    for key, value in inventory.items():
        print(str(value) + ' ' + key)
        item_total += v
    print("Total number of itmes: " + str(item_total))

stuff = addToInventory(stuff, dragonLoot)
displayInventory(stuff)
```

But this show:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Automate the boring stuff with python/testdict.py", line 21, in <module>
    stuff = addToInventory(stuff, dragonLoot)
  File "C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Automate the boring stuff with python/testdict.py", line 8, in addToInventory
    for k, v in (new_inv.items()):
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

P.S: I am new to programing, so can someone also explain in detail what I am missing or what is wrong. Thanks

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: i want to add the items in the list dragonloot to the dict stuff.....eg. there are 42 coins but after adding the dragonLoot it should be 45 and so on...

Comment: Don't iterate over the dictionary at all. Check if list item is **in** dict already. If so, add 1, if not, set 1 (or use an advanced way as described in the answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use a `collections.Counter` to keep your `stuff`:

```
from collections import Counter

stuff = Counter({'rope':1, 'torch':6, 'gold coins':42, 'dagger':1, 'arrow':12})
dragonLoot = ['gold coins', 'dagger', 'gold coins', 'gold coins', 'ruby']

def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    return inventory + Counter(dragonLoot)

stuff = addToInventory(stuff, dragonLoot)
print(stuff)
```

output:

```
Counter({'rope': 1,
         'torch': 6,
         'gold coins': 45,
         'dagger': 2,
         'arrow': 12,
         'ruby': 1})
```

---

if you do not want to use `collections.Counter` module you can use:

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for item in addedItems:
        inventory[item] = inventory.get(item, 0) + 1

    return inventory

stuff = addToInventory(stuff, dragonLoot)
```

output:

```
{'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coins': 45, 'dagger': 2, 'arrow': 12, 'ruby': 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution without using `collections`:

```py
stuff = {'rope':1, 'torch':6, 'gold coins':42, 'dagger':1, 'arrow':12}
dragon_loot = ['gold coins', 'dagger', 'gold coins', 'gold coins', 'ruby']

def add_to_inventory(inventory, added_items):
    inventory_keys = inventory.keys()
    for i in added_items:
        if i in inventory_keys:
            inventory[i] +=1
        else:
            inventory[i] = 1
    return inventory

add_to_inventory(stuff, dragon_loot)
```

Comment: This wont add new items to the inventory, see my edit.

Comment: You forgot to set item count to 1 for new items.

Answer (score 1):

maybe the simplest solution, but it works:

```
def addToInventory(inventory, added_items):
    for i in added_items:
        if i not in inventory:
            inventory.setdefault(i, 1)
        else:
            inventory[i] += 1
   
    return inventory
```